# Incorrect Syntax Saving to an INT field using PHP::PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, syntax-error

Whenever I try to save into an int field.

This is what I did:

```
$query = "Update comments Set comment_authorized = 1 Where id = 4";
$result = $pdo->prepare($query);
$result->execute();
```

This is the error I get:

```
>SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Set comment_authorized = 1 Where (id = 4)' at line 1
```

This same approach works well when inserting into `non-INT` columns. I just don't know why this is not working.

I have debugged this and couldn't just figure it out. After-all, this is a very simple basic statement.

Comment: Are you showing the exact query you used? The error says different.

Comment: And abusing the site by accepting incorrect answer is not the way to go.

Comment: He accepted my answer, can I unaccept this? This doesn't seem right. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
$query = "UPDATE `comments` SET `comment_authorized`=? WHERE `id`=?";
$result = $pdo->prepare($query);
$result->bindParam(1, 1, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$result->bindParam(2, 4, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$result->execute();
```

Comment: Done that but still get the same error. This is very serious and frustrating.
Very basic thing giving this error!
I will try another method anyway.
Thank you once again.

Answer (score -1):

I eventually got this solved without using binding approach as provided above. Surprisingly, this is exactly what I did, I just gave the interpretation of my script's query in the question I posted.

However, I now sanitized each parameter value before using it in the query like this:

`$id = Security::sanitize($id);`

$query = "UPDATE comments SET comment_authorized = 1 WHERE id = $id";
...

Comment: This "sanitization" doesn't make anything "secure" and your query is still vulnerable.

Comment: Thank you anyway. It is just disgusting that the same (->prepared, ->bindValue or ->bindParam, ->execute) query pattern that works well when inserting into non-INT fields failed for int fields. It's horrible and frustrating, you know!